# Converting struct format string to range of allowable int values

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

Python [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library has a bunch of format strings corresponding with a ctype (`"h"`: `int16`, `"H"`: `uint16`).

Is there a simple way to go from a format string (e.g. `"h"`, `"H"`, etc.) to the range of possible values (e.g. -32768 to 32767, 0 to 65535, etc.)?

I see the `struct` library provides [`calcsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.calcsize), but what I really want is something like `calcrange`.

Is there a built-in solution, or an elegant solution I am neglecting?  I am also open to third party libraries.

I have made a DIY `calcrange` below, but it only covers a limited number of possible format strings and makes some non-generalizable assumptions.

```py
def calcrange(fmt: str) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """Calculate the min and max possible value of a given struct format string."""
    size: int = calcsize(fmt)
    unsigned_max = int("0x" + "FF" * size, 16)
    if fmt.islower():
        # Signed case
        min_ = -1 * int("0x80" + "00" * (calcsize(fmt) - 1), 16)
        return min_, unsigned_max + min_
    # Unsigned case
    return 0, unsigned_max
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math can be simplified.  If `b` is the bit-width, then unsigned values are 0 to 2<sup>b</sup>-1 and signed values are -2<sup>(b-1)</sup> to 2<sup>(b-1)</sup>-1.  It only works for the integer types.

Here's a the simplified version:

```py
from typing import *
import struct

def calcrange(intcode):
    b = struct.calcsize(intcode) * 8
    if intcode.islower():
        return -2**(b-1),2**(b-1)-1
    else:
        return 0,2**b-1

for code in 'bBhHiIlLqQnN':
    s,e = calcrange(code)
    print(f'{code} {s:26,} to {e:26,}')
```

Output:

```
b                       -128 to                        127
B                          0 to                        255
h                    -32,768 to                     32,767
H                          0 to                     65,535
i             -2,147,483,648 to              2,147,483,647
I                          0 to              4,294,967,295
l             -2,147,483,648 to              2,147,483,647
L                          0 to              4,294,967,295
q -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to  9,223,372,036,854,775,807
Q                          0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
n -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to  9,223,372,036,854,775,807
N                          0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

Comment: Yes this is more easier to read, great work :) this should be part of the library imo